# Как отключить определенный элемент в Listbox'e при клике

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть Listbox, в нем есть элементы. При клике на определенный элемент выполняется какая-либо функция, а затем выбранный элемент становится неактивным.
Я пытался сделать так, но получал ошибку приведения System.InvalidCastException "Не удалось привести тип объекта "project.MyClass" к типу "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem"."
Что мне нужно исправить?

```
public void DisableListViewItem(int index)
    {
        ListViewItem listViewItem= (ListViewItem)ListQuestions.Items[index];
        listViewItem.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

XAML

```
        <ListView x:Name="ListQuestions" Foreground="{x:Null}" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#FF343131" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="-1,-1,1163,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Вопрос №" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id_Q}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseDown" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Cambria"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFC3C3C3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource mouseOverColor}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

MyClass

```
 public class MyClass
{
    private int _Id;
    private string _Name;

    public int Id_Q { get => _Id; set => _Id = value; }
    public string Name { get => _Name; set => _Name = value; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Реализуйте интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` для класса с данными и вызывайте событие `PropertyChanged`.

```csharp
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Id;
    private string _Name;
    private bool _Enabled = true;

    public int Id_Q { get => _Id; set => _Id = value; }
    public string Name { get => _Name; set => _Name = value; }
    public bool Enabled { get => _Enabled; set { _Enabled = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

2) А в xaml просто используйте `Binding`

```xaml
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}" />
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

3) Затем обращайтесь к свойству `Enabled` экземпляра вашего класса `MyClass` вместо `ListViewItem`. Контрол сам моментально подхватит изменение этого свойства.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я только учусь программировать и не знал, что есть такое свойство.

Comment: @Mersedes не за что, вообще есть шаблон программирования [MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern), там WPF раскрывается на полную катушку, поизучайте на досуге.